# How to post data in DataGridView1 using PostgreSQL as database and vb.net windows forms

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I am new in vb.net, and i hope you guys can help me on this, ive encounter this error "**An error occured: 42601: syntax error at or near "LIKE".** did i miss something in my code? why i am getting this error? I just want that to show my record data in my DataGridView1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData()
    End Sub

Private Sub LoadData(Optional keyword As String = "")
        SQL = "SELECT id, dateSubmitted, lastname, firstname, middleInitial, bodyTemperature, employee_number, address, email, inputdate, inputBy, modifyDate, modifyBy, status, fmCustomerID_id, fmCustomerLocationID_id, fmCustomerSectionID_id, contact_number
    FROM TracingApp_fmcustomeremployeesupplier" & "WHERE CONCAT(lastname, firstname) LIKE @keyword::varchar OR TRIM (middleInitial) LIKE @keyword::varchar ORDER BY id ASC"

        Dim strKeyword As String = String.Format("%(0)%", keyword)

        Cmd = New NpgsqlCommand(SQL, Con)
        Cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("keyword", strKeyword)

        Dim dt As DataTable = PerformCRUD(Cmd)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            intRow = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString())
        Else
            intRow = 0
        End If

        StatusStrip1.Text = "Number of Entry(s): " & intRow.ToString()
        With DataGridView1
            .MultiSelect = False
            .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .DataSource = dt

            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "dateSubmitted"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "lastname"
            .Columns(3).HeaderText = "firstname"
            .Columns(4).HeaderText = "middleInitial"
            .Columns(5).HeaderText = "bodyTemperature"
            .Columns(6).HeaderText = "employee_number"
            .Columns(7).HeaderText = "address"
            .Columns(8).HeaderText = "email"
            .Columns(9).HeaderText = "inputdate"
            .Columns(10).HeaderText = "inputBy"
            .Columns(11).HeaderText = "modifyDate"
            .Columns(12).HeaderText = "modifyBy"
            .Columns(13).HeaderText = "status"
            .Columns(14).HeaderText = "fmCustomerID_id"
            .Columns(15).HeaderText = "fmCustomerLocationID_id"
            .Columns(16).HeaderText = "fmCustomerSectionID_id"
            .Columns(17).HeaderText = "contact_number"

            .Columns(0).Width = 20
            .Columns(1).Width = 150
            .Columns(2).Width = 150
            .Columns(3).Width = 150
            .Columns(4).Width = 150
            .Columns(5).Width = 50
            .Columns(6).Width = 150
            .Columns(7).Width = 150
            .Columns(8).Width = 150
            .Columns(9).Width = 100
            .Columns(10).Width = 100
            .Columns(11).Width = 100
            .Columns(12).Width = 100
            .Columns(13).Width = 100
            .Columns(14).Width = 100
            .Columns(15).Width = 100
            .Columns(16).Width = 100
            .Columns(17).Width = 100

        End With

    End Sub
```

PostgreSQL.vb (module)

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports Npgsql
Module PostgreSQL

    Public Function GetConnectionString() As String
        Dim host As String = "Host=localhost;"
        Dim port As String = "Port=5432;"
        Dim db As String = "Database=tracer;"
        Dim user As String = "Username=****;"
        Dim pass As String = "Password=****;"
        Dim conString As String = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", host, port, db, user, pass)

        Return conString

    End Function

    Public Con As New NpgsqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
    Public Cmd As NpgsqlCommand
    Public SQL As String = ""

    Public Function PerformCRUD(Com As NpgsqlCommand) As DataTable

        Dim da As NpgsqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Try
            da = New NpgsqlDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = Com
            da.Fill(dt)
            Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " & ex.Message, "Database",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function


End Module
```

this is my database

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think there needs to be a space before the word `WHERE` `TracingApp_fmcustomeremployeesupplier" & "WHERE`

Comment: Think JayV is right, but what's the point of the string concatination there anyway?  Why not just TracingApp_fmcustomeremployeesupplier WHERE CONCAT....

Comment: Apparently, you have completely ignored the advice I gave you in may answer to your previous question. Many database object use unmanaged code. The types provide a `.Dispose` method that needs to be called to release these unmanaged resources. `Using...End Using` blocks perform this for you in Ado.net.

Comment: Your PerformCRUD function will only Read, not the other operations in CRUD.

Comment: `intRow = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString())` Why convert what is an Integer to a string then back to an Integer?